# Plugin nativescript-fancyalert not working on Android

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

```
TNSFancyAlert.showSuccess(
    "Success!",
    "Fancy alerts are nice.",
    "Yes they are!",
)
.then(() => {
    console.log("success")
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

the err response is:
[TypeError: cn.refactor.lib.colordialog.PromptDialog is not a constructor]

From: https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-fancyalert

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I met this problem before

Try `rm -rf platforms/android`

And then run `tns run andoid --bundle` again

Hope this helps! Cheers